# Need excel average formula for a dynamic range

Tags: excel

This is what my table looks like:

[image]

Please note that I cannot change the position of any data here. This is a table that will continuously expand as I add new columns to the right and new rows at the bottom.

I need a formula in Column A that will calculate the average of all data in the same row as where the formula is and the formula has to autoupdate whenever I add new columns to the right of the last column. For example, in cell A64 is the formula that will average C64 to E64. when I add new data in F64, I want A64 to autoupdate to include that new cell in the computation.

I tried

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("C64:"&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()+4)))
```

but it did not autoupdate when I added new data in F64. I am not an excel expert and I mostly learn by googling, but this one is taking me forever. Please help.

Comment: Maybe I need to note that the averages showing in my screenshot are not correct because there's really data past E in the original document, but I just wanted to show the layout so I didn't include them in the picture. There will be data past F when I add new columns when next month's data is available. The rows have varying averages. The first row will compute the average of all data in that row. The 2nd row will compute all data in that row except for the last column. The 3rd row will compute all data in that row except for the last 2 columns. And so on.. Hope I answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is where OFFSET and COUNTA are your friends, In A2 and fill down:

```
=AGGREGATE(1,6,OFFSET(C2,,,1,COUNTA(C2:XFD2)))
```

I have used AGGREGATE function with argument 1 for Average and argument 6 to ignore error values in the range. COUNTA resizes the array from C2 to the end of the populated area (allowing for error values).

You can also use INDEX with COUNTA

```
=AGGREGATE(1,6,$C$2:INDEX(C2:XFD2,COUNTA(C2:XFD2)))
```

Or INDEX with MATCH. In the example below, I have reduced the column end point to AA, rather than XFD (which is the last column in 2016). If you know a realistic number of columns that will ever be filled you can use that as your end point reference to reduce the amount of work your dynamic formulas are doing.

```
=AGGREGATE(1,6,$C$2:INDEX(C2:AA2,MATCH(99^99,2:2)))
```

Comment: Did this answer your question please?